# How can I control the source port of a TCP packet?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, nat

To test my implementation of a NAT, I want to send TCP packets from one internal host to two different external hosts, and make sure that the source port for both streams of packets that leave the NAT have the same source port. How can I control the source port? wget uses different source ports for separate TCP connections.

Comment: You didn't state which programming language you intended to use,  the operating system in use, nor did you indicate if you were going to use the standard socket library, command line program, or something else...  I have answers, but you need to elaborate on your questions.  (Hint: short answer is SO_REUSEADDR, but that might not make sense depending on how you are trying to do this.)

Comment: Are the two tests performed concurrently or serially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to try netcat with -p option, if you don't want to write code by yourself, example:
   $ nc -p 31337 www.google.com 80

Here is the explanation for "-p" option from man page:
Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability. It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.

Note though to use any port under 1024 requires root permission.

Comment: He wants to *control* the source port, not just observe it.

Comment: What does observe mean? Use '-p' option did give user the ability to choose among different source ports. Below are copied from man page for netcat(nc)

-p source_port
Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability. It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.

Comment: There is no evidence the OP is using netcat at all. As it is posted here at SO, the presumption is that the OP is programming, not using utilities.

Comment: He explicitly mentioned wget, and wget did not provide the capability to specify source port.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the socket to a specific local port before you connect it.